# Are there any cameras running on Android OS with Instagram support?

Tags: android, instagram

I'm planning to buy a camera. Since I currently use a camera phone, as of now sharing is not a problem, but when I switch to a dedicated camera I would prefer one that runs Android OS, and has built-in Instagram support for sharing.  Does such a camera exist?

Comment: Camera phones such as Samsung galaxy cameras could do cause they ran the android OS. Plus they have nfc (sony cameras and nikon dslr have nfc in built, so u can share pics on the go)

Answer (score 1):

There are smartphone-camera hybrids like Panasonic's CM1 or Samsung's Galaxy Camera. They have android OS running, so I think if you got wifi connection you could probably upload your photos.

However, if you already got a smartphone and a DSLR but without wifi, you may want to look into wifi cards. With those cards you can add wifi functionality to your dslr, transfer photos to your smartphone and then upload it to instagram.

Answer (score 0):

One other option are Sony cameras, such as the Sony a6000. These have WiFi and NFC and allow you to download the image as you take them, thus removing the requirement of Android on the camera itself. The image is downloaded to your phone and from that you can do whatever you want with it.